# Cannot start homestead VM after Win 10 1709 update

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

After installing the latest major Windows update, my Homestead VM would not start any more.

Reverting the Windows update did not fix the issue. I then tried upgrading Vagrant and Virtualbox to the latest versions (2.1 and 5.1.30, then 5.2.2), which made the VM startup get further along, but still does not boot up.

Here are the startup messages and endings of corresponding VBoxHardening.log files at Virtualbox versions 5.1.20, 5.1.30 and 5.2.2:

```
            5.1.20

            Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
            ==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
            ==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
            ==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
            ==> homestead-7: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
                homestead-7: Adapter 1: nat
                homestead-7: Adapter 2: hostonly
            ==> homestead-7: Forwarding ports...
                homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
                homestead-7: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
                homestead-7: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
                homestead-7: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
                homestead-7: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
                homestead-7: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
                homestead-7: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
            ==> homestead-7: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
            ==> homestead-7: Booting VM...
            There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
            for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

            Command: ["startvm", "2e7b1e2c-d8e0-4ec2-b09a-239247061222", "--type", "headless"]

            Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine 'homestead-7' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available in 'C:\Users\sixten\VirtualBox VMs\homestead-7\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'
            VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine



            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffecaba0000 'api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0'
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1 (rcNtResolve=0x0) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000000801:<flags> [calling]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffecaba0000 'api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1'
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffecb760000 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\Wintrust.dll'
            334c.25c4: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> -626 (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll)
            334c.25c4: Error (rc=0):
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: rc=Unknown Status -626 (0xfffffd8e) fImage=1 fProtect=0x0 fAccess=0x0 \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll: Grown load config (244 to 256 bytes) includes non-zero bytes: 00 00 00 00 60 a9 01 80 01 00 00 00
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll
            334c.25c4: Error (rc=0):
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: rejecting 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\bcrypt.dll' (C:\WINDOWS\system32\bcrypt.dll): rcNt=0xc0000190
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0xc0000190 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\bcrypt.dll'
            334c.25c4: Warning! Failed to load bcrypt.dll
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: Processing 'rpcrt4.dll'...
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: 'rpcrt4.dll' -> '\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll' [rcNtRedir=0xc0150008]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/Imports: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: Processing 'sechost.dll'...
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: 'sechost.dll' -> '\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\sechost.dll' [rcNtRedir=0xc0150008]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/Imports: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\sechost.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: Processing 'msvcrt.dll'...
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: 'msvcrt.dll' -> '\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll' [rcNtRedir=0xc0150008]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/Imports: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: Processing 'rpcrt4.dll'...
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: 'rpcrt4.dll' -> '\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll' [rcNtRedir=0xc0150008]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/Imports: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.DLL (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000000001:<flags> [calling]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffecb760000 'C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.DLL'
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.DLL (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000000001:<flags> [calling]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffecb760000 'C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.DLL'
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.DLL (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000000001:<flags> [calling]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffecb760000 'C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.DLL'
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.DLL (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000000001:<flags> [calling]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffecb760000 'C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.DLL'
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.DLL (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000000001:<flags> [calling]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffecb760000 'C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.DLL'
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.DLL (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000000001:<flags> [calling]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffecb760000 'C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.DLL'
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.DLL (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000000001:<flags> [calling]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffecb760000 'C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.DLL'
            334c.25c4: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll)
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   00007ffeca090000 LB 0x00017000 C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll [fFlags=0x0]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheScheduleImports: Import todo: #18 'bcrypt.dll'.
            334c.25c4: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll)
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: Processing 'bcrypt.dll'...
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: 'bcrypt.dll' -> '\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll' [rcNtRedir=0xc0150008]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/Imports: cache hit (Unknown Status -626 (0xfffffd8e)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
            334c.25c4: Error (rc=0):
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/Imports: cached rc=Unknown Status -626 (0xfffffd8e) fImage=1 fProtect=0x0 fAccess=0x0 cHits=1 \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000000001:<flags> [calling]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/NtCreateSection: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/NtCreateSection: cache hit (Unknown Status -626 (0xfffffd8e)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
            334c.25c4: Error (rc=0):
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedScreenImage/NtCreateSection: cached rc=Unknown Status -626 (0xfffffd8e) fImage=1 fProtect=0x10 fAccess=0xf cHits=2 \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll
            334c.25c4: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0xc0000190 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll'
            334c.25c4: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrust: WinVerifyTrust failed with 0x8 (<NULL>) on '\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe'
            334c.25c4: Error -22919 in VBoxHeadless! (enmWhat=1)
            334c.25c4: WinVerifyTrust failed on stub executable: WinVerifyTrust failed with hrc=Unknown Status 0x8 on '\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe'
            18bc.1f64: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor[2]: Quitting: ExitCode=0x1 (rcNtWait=0x0, rcNt1=0x0, rcNt2=0x103, rcNt3=0x103, 84 ms, the end);
            b8c.2d8: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor[1]: Quitting: ExitCode=0x1 (rcNtWait=0x0, rcNt1=0x0, rcNt2=0x103, rcNt3=0x103, 778 ms, the end);














            5.1.30

            Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
            ==> homestead-7: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
            ==> homestead-7: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
            ==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
            ==> homestead-7: Setting the name of the VM: homestead-7
            ==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
            ==> homestead-7: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
                homestead-7: Adapter 1: nat
                homestead-7: Adapter 2: hostonly
            ==> homestead-7: Forwarding ports...
                homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
                homestead-7: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
                homestead-7: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
                homestead-7: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
                homestead-7: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
                homestead-7: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
                homestead-7: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
            ==> homestead-7: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
            ==> homestead-7: Booting VM...
            ==> homestead-7: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
                homestead-7: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
                homestead-7: SSH username: vagrant
                homestead-7: SSH auth method: private key
            Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
            Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
            the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.


            23cc.32a8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffec61e0000 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\winmm.dll'
            23cc.32a8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffec61e0000 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\winmm.dll'
            23cc.32a8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffec61e0000 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\winmm.dll'
            23cc.32a8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\dsound.dll
            23cc.32a8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\WINDOWS\system32\dsound.dll (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000000001:<flags> [calling]
            23cc.32a8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffeaf460000 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\dsound.dll'
            23cc.32a8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffec61e0000 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\winmm.dll'
            23cc.804: '\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\tzres.dll' has no imports
            23cc.804: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 22900 (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\tzres.dll)
            23cc.804: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\tzres.dll
            23cc.804: supR3HardenedMonitor_NtCreateSection: NtMapViewOfSection failed on 0000000000000dc8 (hFile=00000000000007bc) with 0xc0000022 -> STATUS_TRUST_FAILURE
            23cc.804: supR3HardenedScreenImage/NtCreateSection: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\tzres.dll [avoiding WinVerifyTrust]
            23cc.804: supR3HardenedMonitor_NtCreateSection: NtMapViewOfSection failed on 00000000000007bc (hFile=0000000000000dc8) with 0xc0000022 -> STATUS_TRUST_FAILURE








            5.2.2

            Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
            ==> homestead-7: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
            ==> homestead-7: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
            ==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
            ==> homestead-7: Setting the name of the VM: homestead-7
            ==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
            ==> homestead-7: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
                homestead-7: Adapter 1: nat
                homestead-7: Adapter 2: hostonly
            ==> homestead-7: Forwarding ports...
                homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
                homestead-7: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
                homestead-7: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
                homestead-7: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
                homestead-7: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
                homestead-7: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
                homestead-7: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
            ==> homestead-7: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
            ==> homestead-7: Booting VM...
            ==> homestead-7: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
                homestead-7: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
                homestead-7: SSH username: vagrant
                homestead-7: SSH auth method: private key
            Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
            Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
            the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.


            22ec.1680: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\dsound.dll
            22ec.1680: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\WINDOWS\system32\dsound.dll (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000000001:<flags> [calling]
            22ec.1680: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffb25b10000 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\dsound.dll'
            22ec.1680: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\winmm.dll
            22ec.1680: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\WINDOWS\System32\winmm.dll (Input=winmm.dll, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000000001:<flags> [calling]
            22ec.1680: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ffb38f60000 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\winmm.dll'
            22ec.c84: '\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\tzres.dll' has no imports
            22ec.c84: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 22900 (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\tzres.dll)
            22ec.c84: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\tzres.dll
            22ec.c84: supR3HardenedMonitor_NtCreateSection: NtMapViewOfSection failed on 0000000000000e4c (hFile=000000000000084c) with 0xc0000022 -> STATUS_TRUST_FAILURE
            22ec.c84: supR3HardenedScreenImage/NtCreateSection: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\tzres.dll [avoiding WinVerifyTrust]
            22ec.c84: supR3HardenedMonitor_NtCreateSection: NtMapViewOfSection failed on 000000000000084c (hFile=0000000000000e4c) with 0xc0000022 -> STATUS_TRUST_FAILURE
```

Thanks

Comment: I had similar issues with an ubuntu/xenial64 vagrant box (also on Windows 10), I was running the box under c:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\<boxname>. Errors went away when I recreated the box under my own user folder.